# Engine ignition AC frequency

Tags: frequency

What is the (minimal, usual, maximal) AC frequency of petrol engine ignition (at the spark plug electrodes)? I'm interested mainly in cars and garden machinery.

Also, I found that dielectric strength of air under normal conditions is higher than of mixture in the engine cylinder at ignition point. Is it true?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an image from a PicoScope probe: -

[image]

And [here's](http://www.picoauto.com/waveform/Ignition/Secondary/wave79.html) the article - you can even download the waveform file. I'm not saying this fully answers the question, I'm offering this up as a result of 1 minute googling. I'm sure if 10 minutes were spent you might get maximums and minimums etc..

OK 1 minute more and I got what is someone's impression of the above but including a spark line: -

[image]

Still from the same website.

Comment: Why cannot I google any circuit schematics of secondary ignition probes, scopes? Can you help me once more?